# Problemas en Navegacion Xamarin Prism MasterPage

Tags: xamarin, prism

Estoy usando una MasterPage con Xamarin Prism.
El redireccionamiento del mennu trabaja muy bien, el problema esta en que por ejemplo navego del MasterPage a la ViewA o ViewB o ViewC...etc y al usar el botón físico del dispositivo no navega a la Page previa, si no que cierra la App por completo.

Este es la estructura de la MasterPage

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <NavigationPage Title="Menu" BarBackgroundColor="#006b68">
        <x:Arguments>
            <ContentPage>
                <!--Aquí los ítems de navegación-->
            </ContentPage>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:MainPage/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Y así es como establesco la navegación en el App.xml.cs

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(MainDetailPage) + "/" + nameof(NavigationPage) + "/" + nameof(MainPage));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve un problema similar y el código que me ayudó fue este:

```
var childViewCount = ((ViewGroup)((Activity)MainActivity.Instance).Window.DecorView).ChildCount;

        if (Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.SendBackPressed())
        {
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(true);
            return;
        }
        if (Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.Count > 0)
        {
            base.OnBackPressed();
            return;
        }
        // Check if a non modal page has been pushed, if any modal page or popups are open
        if (Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 1 ||
                childViewCount > 2)
        {
            base.OnBackPressed();
            //await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync(true);
            return;
        }

        if (_backToExitPressedOnce)
        {
            base.OnBackPressed();
            Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Exit(0);
            return;
        }

        this._backToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Tap again to exit", ToastLength.Short).Show();

        new Handler().PostDelayed(() => { _backToExitPressedOnce = false; }, 2000);`
```

en el main activity del proyecto android sobreescribiendo

```
public async override void OnBackPressed()
```

yo estoy usando algunos plugins espero te sirva.